# Download file from URL with redirection, completely automatic at the CLI, replacing browser operation

Tags: php, curl, url

I have asked [Download file from URL with redirection, "?" and other symbols, from the command line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/651995/download-file-from-url-with-redirection-and-other-symbols-from-the-command)

`curl -L` did not get the correct file right away.
A couple of comments pointed to a way involving some "manual" work/parsing that hopefully works with other redirected URLs from `eclipse.org`.

So my current question is somewhat different:

**Is there any way for curl (or some other means) to handle as many cases (including the linked one), that proceeds automatically to *get the same file I would get by using a browser*?**
The evidence shows that `curl -L` does not work on its own.
I know I could write my own parser, but I am referring to a possible **existing solution**, via curl or other CLI command/script.

I am a complete newbie regarding redirection methods.